# MS SQL Manegement Studio Create Database task

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I need to know if the "Backup Database Task" in MS SQL Management Studio, maintenance plans, takes the free space into account or that it only backsup the data part.

For e.g. if the db size is 100 MB where 60Mb is data and 40Mb is free space. Will take the backup of the whole db of size 100 or that it will take backup of the 60Mb data.

I couldn't find this info on MS site.

MOVED TO:
[Microsoft Sql Server Managment studio backup size goes negative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457600/microsoft-sql-server-managment-studio-backup-size-goes-negative)

Comment: @Frank please stop making trivial edits to remove a single tag, you are bumping a lot of old posts to be active again and it's not at all necessary.

Comment: @bluefeet Sorry about all that. It won't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

Backing up the database will only backup the actual data not the free space.

Not sure why you have mentioned "Create Database Task" though?

Comment: My bad its "Backup Database Task", in the Maintenance Plans.